# Rach's Prelude in C Sharp minor

Tags: piano, notation, terminology

It's been eons since I took piano lessons and I can't remember much of anything regarding markings.

Can someone please tell me what that little x is in the third bar of Rach's piece?  (Actually, there are two of them.) What's it called and what does it mean?

Thanks!

Comment: So if it's a double sharp, why the heck don't composers just put in the note they want it to be?!  (I know...  it's a dumb question, but I had to ask anyway.  LOL)

Comment: They do.  When they use F**x**, it's because the note is acting as F**x** (probably as a leading tone to G♯) in the context of a key that has many sharps in it. I wrote a piece recently in D♯ minor, and there were C**x**s in it, because D isn't a note native to that key.

Answer (score 0):

It's a double-sharp.  It means to play a note two half-steps higher than the note associated with the line or space where the note is written.  In this case, it's an f-double-sharp, which is enharmonically equivalent to a g.